# How to check equality between number and string converted to number (vectorized)

Tags: r, vectorization, precision, outliers

I want to find the index of the outlier spotted by the `grubbs.test` function of the `outliers` package (I adapted it from another SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22841478/3871924))

```
where = function(x) which(x==as.numeric(strsplit(grubbs.test(x)$alternative," ")[[1]][3]))
```

It works by retrieving the number in the text displayed by the grubbs result. It's kind of a hack but it works well, let's say, for round numbers:

```
df=c(0, 3, rnorm(10))
where(df) #[1] 2
```

When it gets to decimal numbers, the text doesn't match all the times with the digits of the actual number:

```
df=c(0, sqrt(10), rnorm(10))
where(df) # integer(0)
```

Someone has an idea to fix that problem? Or another way to find the index of the grubbs test biggest outlier? I'm trying to use this in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `strsplit` returns stings instead of numbers. In your second example I get:

```
[1] "highest"          "value"            "3.16227766016838" "is"               "an"               "outlier"
```

but the third element is not really the character version of the number `3.16227766016838`. In fact the real number returned from `grubbs.test` might have a lot more decimal places and this is why the `==` operator does not 'catch' it as an equality. This can be seen clearly here:

```
a<-sqrt(10)
> a == as.numeric(as.character(a))
[1] FALSE
```

Is there a solution to this?

**YES** there is.

In order to tackle this problem just use the `almost.equal` function that I took the liberty to copy from [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Vectorized-forms-of-isTRUE-identical-and-all-equal-td1755698.html) R-help post:

```
almost.equal <- function (x, y, tolerance=.Machine$double.eps^0.5,
                          na.value=TRUE)
{
  answer <- rep(na.value, length(x))
  test <- !is.na(x)
  answer[test] <- abs(x[test] - y) < tolerance
  answer
}
```

The above function is a vectorized form of the `all.equal` function which checks for an 'approximate' equality so that it captures cases like yours.

Let's convert your function to:

```
where = function(x) {
  which(almost.equal(x, as.numeric(strsplit(grubbs.test(x)$alternative," ")[[1]][3])))
}
```

And let's check it now:

```
> df=c(0, 3, rnorm(10))
> where(df)
[1] 2
```

And:

```
> df=c(0, sqrt(10), rnorm(10))
> where(df)
[1] 2
```

And you have a solution that works well with decimal numbers too!!

Comment: thanks, your adapted function works perfectly! that's what i needed.