# Replacing values in df using index

Tags: r, outliers

I am trying to detect outliers in my dataframe and replace the outliers by NAs. 
I have slighty modified the function provided in here: [How to repeat the Grubbs test and flag the outliers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837099/how-to-repeat-the-grubbs-test-and-flag-the-outliers). When trying the function for a vector it works great, but my problem is when I use it on a dataframe. The function detects outliers but I do not know how to get the results as dataframe.

What I want as a result is my original dataframe replaced by `NA`s. Where `NA`will be the detected outliers.

This is what I have tried until now:

```
library(outliers)
data("rock")

# Function to detect outliers with Grubbs test in a vector
grubbs.flag <- function(vector) {
outliers <- NULL
test <- vector
grubbs.result <- grubbs.test(test)
pv <- grubbs.result$p.value
# throw an error if there are too few values for the Grubb's test
 if (length(test) < 3 ) stop("Grubb's test requires > 2 input values")
 while(pv < 0.05) {
outliers <- c(outliers,as.numeric(strsplit(grubbs.result$alternative," ")[[1]][3]))
test <- vector[!vector %in% outliers]
# stop if all but two values are flagged as outliers
if (length(test) < 3 ) {
  warning("All but two values flagged as outliers")
  break
}
grubbs.result <- grubbs.test(test)
pv <- grubbs.result$p.value
idx.outlier <- which(vector %in% outliers)
na.vect <- replace(vector, idx.outlier, NA)

}
return(na.vect)
}

# Function to detect outliers with Grubbs test in a dataframe
Grubbs.df <- function(data){
grubbs.data <- (as.vector(unlist(apply(data, grubbs.flag))))
return(grubbs.data)
}
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: I guess something to do with your apply and as.vector in the end of the script. I'll run it on my laptop and see for you what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add this before the while loop:

```
na.vect <- test
```

Because if it breaks beforehand, your na.vect won't exist and will thus throw an error. And then just run it on your dataframe like this:

```
apply(rock,2,grubbs.flag)
```

The second argument 2 tells to apply it to the columns of the dataframe. Use 1 for rows.